# phpmyadmin is showing code instead of login page

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I installed all the necessary programs like Apache, Mysql, Php etc. and configured them right from the steps I was given but when I try to access the phpmyadmin login page it shows a long list of code. I've seen other posts talking about this issue but I don't see any one-right answer.

If you could help that would be great, the code I'm seeing on the phpmyadmin page is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBLG0.jpg